# Mysql Rollup repeatingid field

Tags: mysql, group-by, rollup

I have the following query result using group by with rollup:

```
Divison Department      Section     Employee Name   Employee ID Hours

Assets  Asset Strategy  Not Defined Monty Mouse     480193      64.00
Assets  Asset Strategy  Not Defined Frank Flint     480165      67.50
Assets  Asset Strategy  Not Defined                 480165      131.50
Assets  Asset Strategy                              480165      131.50
Assets  Event Centre    Not Defined Sally Spoons    800192      72.00
Assets  Event Centre    Not Defined Randolph Smith  800199      37.50
Assets  Event Centre    Not Defined Petra Peters    800195      64.00
Assets  Event Centre    Not Defined                 800195      173.50
Assets  Event Centre                                800195      173.50
```

What I want to be able to do is to stop the employee id from replicating in the rollup lines:

```
Divison Department      Section     Employee Name   Employee ID Hours

Assets  Asset Strategy  Not Defined Monty Mouse     480193      64.00
Assets  Asset Strategy  Not Defined Frank Flint     480165      67.50
Assets  Asset Strategy  Not Defined                             131.50
Assets  Asset Strategy                                          131.50
Assets  Event Centre    Not Defined Sally Spoons    800192      72.00
Assets  Event Centre    Not Defined Randolph Smith  800199      37.50
Assets  Event Centre    Not Defined Petra Peters    800195      64.00
Assets  Event Centre    Not Defined                             173.50
Assets  Event Centre                                            173.50
```

I've read other posts about using union to try to just match up the employee if from a non-rollup query, but this hasn't worked for me.

I've also read about using sub-select (wrapping) to get the employee id, but this has just lead to the same result.

My rollup statement groups by division, department, section and employee name. If I try to add employee id to this clause I get a rollup on every change of employee. I've also changed the order of the name and if fields and tried grouping by the id rather than the name, but this has just replicated the name in the same way the id is above.

Am I chasing the impossible dream here? Is it not actually possible to display the data in this way? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

For those that would like the full query code, here it is:

```
select distinct
  hr_func_desc('CD_DEPT_', p.department) as 'Department',
  hr_func_desc('CD_DIVN_', p.division) as 'Division',
  hr_func_desc('CD_SECT_', p.section) as 'Section',
  pe.payroll_name as 'Employee Name',
  pe.employee_id as 'Employee ID',
  max(e.termination_date) as 'Termination Date',
  sum(ph.ordinary_hours) as 'Ordinary Hours',
  sum(ph.overtime_1_hours) as 'Overtime 1 Hours',
  sum(ph.overtime_2_hours) as 'Overtime 2 Hours',
  sum(ph.overtime_1_hours) + sum(ph.overtime_2_hours) as 'Total Overtime Hours',
  sum(ph.ordinary_hours) + sum(ph.overtime_1_hours) + sum(ph.overtime_2_hours) as 'Total Hours Worked',
  sum(al.units) as 'Number of Standby Worked',
  sum(ph.statutory_hours) as 'Statutory Holidays',
  sum(ph.annual_leave_hours) as 'Annual Leave',
  sum(ph.long_service_leave_hours) as 'Long Service Leave',
  sum(ph.special_leave_hours) as 'Special Leave',
  sum(ph.time_in_alt_hours) as 'Alt Lieu',
  sum(ph.parental_leave_hours) as 'Parental Leave',
  sum(ph.sick_hours) as 'Sick',
  sum(ph.domestic_leave_hours) as 'Domestic',
  sum(ph.bereavement_hours) as 'Bereavement',
  sum(ph.acc_week_1_hours) as 'ACC Week 1',
  sum(ph.acc_hours) as 'ACC Unpaid',
  sum(ph.lwop_hours) as 'Leave Without Pay',
  sum(ph.sick_hours) + sum(ph.domestic_leave_hours) + sum(ph.bereavement_hours) + sum(ph.annual_leave_hours) + sum(ph.statutory_hours) +
sum(ph.special_leave_hours) + sum(ph.long_service_leave_hours) + sum(ph.time_in_lieu_hours) + sum(ph.time_in_alt_hours) + sum(ph.lwop_hours) +
sum(ph.standby_leave_hours) + sum(ph.parental_leave_hours) + sum(ph.acc_week_1_hours) + sum(ph.acc_hours) as 'Total Hours Absent',
  sum(ph.ordinary_hours) + sum(ph.overtime_1_hours) + sum(ph.overtime_2_hours) + sum(ph.statutory_hours) + sum(ph.annual_leave_hours) + 
sum(ph.long_service_leave_hours) + sum(ph.special_leave_hours) + sum(ph.time_in_alt_hours) + sum(ph.sick_hours) + sum(ph.domestic_leave_hours)  +
sum(ph.bereavement_hours) + sum(ph.acc_week_1_hours) as 'Total Hours Paid',
  hr_func_normal_hours(pe.employee_id) as 'Normal Hours Worked per Week',
  sum(cast(pt.pay_weeks as unsigned integer)) as 'Pay Weeks for Period Chosen',
  round((sum(ph.ordinary_hours) + sum(ph.overtime_1_hours) + sum(ph.overtime_2_hours) + sum(ph.sick_hours) + sum(ph.domestic_leave_hours) +
   sum(ph.bereavement_hours) + sum(ph.statutory_hours) + sum(ph.special_leave_hours) + sum(ph.time_in_lieu_hours) + sum(ph.time_in_alt_hours) +
   sum(ph.lwop_hours) + sum(ph.acc_week_1_hours) + sum(ph.acc_hours) + sum(ph.standby_leave_hours) + sum(ph.parental_leave_hours))
/sum(cast(pt.pay_weeks as unsigned integer)), 2) as 'Calculated FTE Hours',
  truncate(((sum(ph.ordinary_hours) + sum(ph.overtime_1_hours) + sum(ph.overtime_2_hours) + sum(ph.sick_hours) + sum(ph.domestic_leave_hours) +
   sum(ph.bereavement_hours) + sum(ph.statutory_hours) + sum(ph.special_leave_hours) + sum(ph.time_in_lieu_hours) + sum(ph.time_in_alt_hours) +
   sum(ph.lwop_hours) + sum(ph.acc_week_1_hours) + sum(ph.acc_hours) + sum(ph.standby_leave_hours) + sum(ph.parental_leave_hours))
/sum(cast(pt.pay_weeks as unsigned integer)))/hr_func_normal_hours(pe.employee_id), 3) as 'Calculated FTE'
from swpayroll.py_employees pe
  left outer join swhr_rails.hr_employees e on e.id = pe.employee_id
  left outer join swhr_rails.hr_employee_positions ep on pe.employee_id = ep.employee_id
  left outer join swhr_rails.hr_positions p on ep.position_id = p.id
  left outer join swpayroll.py_rep_hist_hours ph on pe.employee_id = ph.employee_id
  left outer join swpayroll.py_hist_dedns_allowances al
    on al.employee_id = pe.employee_id
       and al.pay_date = ph.pay_date
       and al.da_id in (33, 66, 67)
  left outer join swpayroll.py_hist_totals pt on pt.employee_id = pe.employee_id and pt.pay_date = ph.pay_date
where ep.position_id = (select min(x.position_id) from swhr_rails.hr_employee_positions as x 
                         where x.employee_id = pe.employee_id and x.position_end is null)
      and ph.pay_date between '2012-10-21' and '2012-11-04'
group by
  hr_func_desc('CD_DEPT_', p.department),
  hr_func_desc('CD_DIVN_', p.division),
  hr_func_desc('CD_SECT_', p.section),
  pe.payroll_name with rollup;
```

Smaller snippit of code:

```
select distinct
  hr_func_desc('CD_DEPT_', p.department) as 'Department',
  hr_func_desc('CD_DIVN_', p.division) as 'Division',
  hr_func_desc('CD_SECT_', p.section) as 'Section',
  pe.payroll_name as 'Employee Name',
  pe.employee_id as 'Employee ID',
  sum(ph.ordinary_hours) as 'Ordinary Hours'
from swpayroll.py_employees pe
  left outer join swhr_rails.hr_employees e on e.id = pe.employee_id
  left outer join swhr_rails.hr_employee_positions ep on pe.employee_id = ep.employee_id
  left outer join swhr_rails.hr_positions p on ep.position_id = p.id
  left outer join swpayroll.py_rep_hist_hours ph on pe.employee_id = ph.employee_id
  left outer join swpayroll.py_hist_dedns_allowances al
    on al.employee_id = pe.employee_id
       and al.pay_date = ph.pay_date
       and al.da_id in (33, 66, 67)
  left outer join swpayroll.py_hist_totals pt on pt.employee_id = pe.employee_id and pt.pay_date = ph.pay_date
where ep.position_id = (select min(x.position_id) from swhr_rails.hr_employee_positions as x 
                         where x.employee_id = pe.employee_id and x.position_end is null)
      and ph.pay_date between '2012-10-21' and '2012-11-04'
group by
  hr_func_desc('CD_DEPT_', p.department),
  hr_func_desc('CD_DIVN_', p.division),
  hr_func_desc('CD_SECT_', p.section),
  pe.payroll_name with rollup;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, having posted the same question in the mysql.com forums (http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,577674,577674#msg-577674), there is no way to eliminate this repetition at query time.

It would need to be done programatically via a secondary procedural language.